# How can I redirect an IIS website to use www

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

As a user trying to access https://www.qa1.samplewebsite.org

I want to be redirected to https://qa1.samplewebsite.org

The site without www works just fine but when www is appended, it says 'Can't reach the page'

Used url rewrite 2 rules but didn't work

The web.config section is as follows:

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>                
     <rule name="Remove WWW" stopProcessing="true">   
     <match url="^(.*)$" />    
     <conditions> 
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />  
     </conditions>   
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
     </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Edit the question and show what's the current status. If you already have rewrite/redirection rules in your `web.config` file, show them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect www to non www, you can refer to this rule:

```
<rule name="Remove WWW" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I have tried the above config but it did not seem to work.

Comment: I edited my answer to change `{C:1}` to `{C:2}`, please try again.

Comment: thanks but it's still giving the site not found error

Comment: Can you directly access `https://qa1.samplewebsite.org` to display the page?

Comment: Yes I can directly access ```https://qa1.samplewebsite.org``` but not ```https://www.qa1.samplewebsite.org``` It's showing site not found error in the latter

Comment: `<system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
            <rules>                
                <rule name="Remove WWW" stopProcessing="true">   <match url="^(.*)$" />    
                <conditions> <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />  
                  </conditions>   <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
   </rewrite>
</system.webServer>`
This is the exact snippet from the web.config file

Comment: It works fine in my test, try to use [failed request trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.